# Stored proc orders results differently than when run in query analyzer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc that returns the below values when called:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Activities_GetCrazyTables]
        @iActivity = 49,
        @iLanding = 6,
        @iFirst = 1,
        @iLast = 10,
        @strSearch = '',
        @bActiveOnly = 0
```

<kbd>orderkey</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_rownum</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_id</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_name</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>2022</kbd>      
    <kbd>Cow Mountain</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>2055</kbd>      <kbd>Lake Mendocino</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>2099</kbd>      <kbd>Chandelier</kbd>

However when I execute the actual code of the stored proc in the query analyzer, it returns the results differently:

<kbd>orderkey</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_rownum</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_id</kbd><kbd>yellowpage_name</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>1</kbd>      <kbd>2022</kbd>      
    <kbd>Chandelier</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>2</kbd>      <kbd>2055</kbd>      <kbd>Cow Mountain</kbd>
    <kbd>table4</kbd>      <kbd>3</kbd>      <kbd>2099</kbd>      <kbd>Lake Mendocino</kbd>

Why do I get the proper sort order when I run the query stand alone compared to when I execute the stored proc?

The code of the stored proc is below:

```
set @strSearch = LOWER(@strSearch)

select orderkey, y.* from 
(
    /* get the featured sponsors in order specified in the database */
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.orderkey) as yellowpage_rownum, x.* 
    from (
    /* top tier featured 1-5 */
    select yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, story_count,
    'table1' as orderkey, yellowpage_active from
    (select top 5 a.* from 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by yellowpage_name) as rownum, yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, (select COUNT(storyyellowpage_story) from storyyellowpagexref join stories on (story_id=storyyellowpage_story) where story_active=1 and storyyellowpage_yellowpage=y.yellowpage_id) as story_count, yellowpage_active
    from yellowpageactivityxref 
    join activities on (activity_id=yellowpageactivity_activity) 
    join yellowpages y on (yellowpage_id=yellowpageactivity_yellowpage) 
    join landingcities on (landingcity_city=yellowpage_city) 
    where yellowpageactivity_activity=@iActivity and landingcity_landing=@iLanding and yellowpage_featuredsponsor=1 and 
        (LOWER(yellowpage_name) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%' or LOWER(yellowpage_address1) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%')) as a 
    where a.rownum between 1 and 5 order by newid()) as b
    union all
    /* top tier featured 6-10 */
    select yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, story_count,
    'table2' as orderkey, yellowpage_active from
    (select top 5 a.* from 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by yellowpage_name) as rownum, yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, (select COUNT(storyyellowpage_story) from storyyellowpagexref join stories on (story_id=storyyellowpage_story) where story_active=1 and storyyellowpage_yellowpage=y.yellowpage_id) as story_count, yellowpage_active
    from yellowpageactivityxref 
    join activities on (activity_id=yellowpageactivity_activity) 
    join yellowpages y on (yellowpage_id=yellowpageactivity_yellowpage) 
    join landingcities on (landingcity_city=yellowpage_city) 
    where yellowpageactivity_activity=@iActivity and landingcity_landing=@iLanding and yellowpage_featuredsponsor=1 and 
        (LOWER(yellowpage_name) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%' or LOWER(yellowpage_address1) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%')) as a 
    where a.rownum between 6 and 10 order by newid()) as b
    union all
    /* top tier featured 11-15 */
    select yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, story_count,
    'table3' as orderkey, yellowpage_active from
    (select top 5 a.* from 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by yellowpage_name) as rownum, yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, (select COUNT(storyyellowpage_story) from storyyellowpagexref join stories on (story_id=storyyellowpage_story) where story_active=1 and storyyellowpage_yellowpage=y.yellowpage_id) as story_count, yellowpage_active
    from yellowpageactivityxref 
    join activities on (activity_id=yellowpageactivity_activity) 
    join yellowpages y on (yellowpage_id=yellowpageactivity_yellowpage) 
    join landingcities on (landingcity_city=yellowpage_city) 
    where yellowpageactivity_activity=@iActivity and landingcity_landing=@iLanding and yellowpage_featuredsponsor=1 and 
        (LOWER(yellowpage_name) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%' or LOWER(yellowpage_address1) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%')) as a 
    where a.rownum between 11 and 15 order by newid()) as b
    union all
    /* get the rest and sort by name */
    select yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, story_count,
    'table4' as orderkey, yellowpage_active from
    (select top 2147483647 a.* from 
    (select yellowpage_id, yellowpage_name, yellowpage_address1, yellowpage_address2, yellowpage_city, yellowpage_state, yellowpage_zip, 
    yellowpage_phone, yellowpage_url, yellowpage_latitude, yellowpage_longitude, yellowpage_featuredsponsor, yellowpage_premium, yellowpage_order, 
    yellowpageactivity_order, (select COUNT(storyyellowpage_story) from storyyellowpagexref join stories on (story_id=storyyellowpage_story) where story_active=1 and storyyellowpage_yellowpage=y.yellowpage_id) as story_count, yellowpage_active
    from yellowpageactivityxref 
    join activities on (activity_id=yellowpageactivity_activity) 
    join yellowpages y on (yellowpage_id=yellowpageactivity_yellowpage) 
    join landingcities on (landingcity_city=yellowpage_city) 
    where yellowpageactivity_activity=@iActivity and landingcity_landing=@iLanding and yellowpage_featuredsponsor=0 and 
        (LOWER(yellowpage_name) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%' or LOWER(yellowpage_address1) LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%')) as a 
    order by yellowpage_name) as b
    ) as x
    ) as y where y.yellowpage_rownum between @iFirst and @iLast
```

Comment: Please don't use `<kbd>` for showing sample data. Well, not that it's any uglier than your query, but... ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (the results of the Union) is running without an order by statement. This means the order of the results is not deterministic which means it can be different in different runs.

To fix this, you need to add an Order by Statement after the last where statement:

```
as y where y.yellowpage_rownum between @iFirst and @iLast Order by col1, col2
```

You should also eliminate the order by yellowpage_name statement in the last query as that will have nothing to do with the ordering of the final result set.

Answer (score 1):

That's one hell of a query, so it's difficult to fathom exactly what is happening. However, you are missing an `Order By` on the full result set.

SQL Server is a **relational** database. That is the key concept here.  Unless you specifically define what you want the order to be the database engine makes no guarantees about the order of the rows that are returned. You could use exactly the same query in two different places and get a different order of results.

In relational theory, the set (A, B, C) is the same as (C, B, A). Order is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you order by orderkey which is not unique. rows having the same orderkey do not necessarily appear in the same order.

Extend your `order by` clause to solve the problem.

Comment: The OP doesn't `ORDER BY` at all. Yes, there is an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause, but this does not necessarily affect the end result.

Comment: Look closer. The yellowpage_rownum is different and that is what might/will cause problems. If the rows appear in a different order, I personally would not mind, but the sort order implied by the `OVER` get things mixed up.